# Getting garbage after tripledes_cbc encryption with NoPadding scheme

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, tripledes

I am doing decryption of some encrypted data. Say the data is a highly confindential information. The information is encryoted with `tripledes_cbc` algorithm. The secret key used to encrypt the information is encrypted with `rsa` algorithm.

But when I try to decrypt the information with `DESede/CBC/NoPadding` algorithm, I get the original data along with some garbage characters padded at the front and at the end.

When I try to use `DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` instead of `DESede/CBC/NoPadding`, I get 'final block not properly padded' exception.

Following is the code snippet. Please let me know what can I do to get the correct text with no extra padding:

```
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ksFile);
        ks.load(fis, "testing".toCharArray());

        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("keys", "1234".toCharArray());

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] kekBytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encKey.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[8];
        random.nextBytes(iv);

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(kekBytes, "DESede");
        Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] out = cipher1.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        System.out.println("Data Length: " + out.length);
        String result = new String(out, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: 1. 3DES should not be used for new work, AES is the current symmetric method to use. But my guess, this is a school project and schools are a decade or so behind the real world. 2. Provide an example of the excpected and decrypted data **in hex format**.

Comment: Obviously you need to find out what padding was used by the encrypting side. Also, are you using DES or DESede? Because `DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` is not a sensible alternative to `DESede/CBC/NoPadding`. Perhaps you meant `DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding`?

Answer (score 0):

Your key is correct if the middle part is correct. The block at the beginning is probably the IV that was prefixed to the ciphertext. If you try to decrypt that then you'll get garbage. After that the IV itself is taken as vector for the next block, so the CBC cipher manages to correct itself and continues correctly. Theoretically: CBC has limited *error propagation*.

The part at the end is the padding scheme used. You should try `"DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`. If that doesn't work you need to take a look at the binary values (indeed, e.g. hex encoded) and find out the padding scheme which is used so you can unpad your data.

Note that there aren't that many padding schemes in the standard cryptography providers for Java. So you either have to find a provider that provides e.g. bit padding or you can use `"NoPadding"` and perform the unpadding yourself.

If this is for an online protocol it might be time to learn about padding oracle attacks and, indeed, more up-to-date protocols such as AES/GCM and RSA/OAEP.

Comment: How do I identify pading chars from hexadecimal representation of the decrypted message? The hex result looks like (only first & last few chars given here) :  "5368f1b5beaa10ec3c6e73313a5061796d656e7443616c6c6261636b496e707574 .....................7443616c6c6261636b496e7075743ec9de7dc99f437f08   "

Comment: @K.Nath Allowing for some inadvertent invisible characters in the above hex encoded data the format is 8-bytes of preamble followed by ASCII encoded text followed by 8-bytes of data. Why do you think this is incorrect?

Comment: @zaph - I did not mean the output was incorrect. I just wanted to extract the text excluding the padded garbage. I could overcome the garbage padded at the front of the output string by eliminating the first 16 chars ( in the above comment - '5368f1b5beaa10ec' ) as I see first 16 chars always differ every time I run the java code. But I am not able remove garbage from the tail of the output string as except the first 16 chars as mentioned, all other characters remain same every time I run the java code.

Comment: @K.Nath so it is not a decryption problem, just a byte manipulation issue. It seems that what you want always ends with a ">" characrter (0x3e) so just find the first ">" from the end and delete past it.

Comment: Its probably ISO padding which means the amount of padding bytes is encoded in the last byte.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Great, even easier! I saw the 0x08 but I am not familiar with [ISO padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#ISO_10126).

Comment: @zaph It's an old padding mode, largely unused now. It has a lot of the drawbacks of ISO padding with the additional problem that the previous bytes are supposed to be random (or any value, but generally random). Of course, having to request additional bytes from a PRNG is not very efficient; the PRNG is often a lot less efficient than the block cipher itself and often requires a call to the OS. Tnx for the link, was on mobile at the kayaking club.